# management.azure.com REST API returns "200 ok " with an empty JSON array but the same API when called in the MS docs REST API Try It Returns results

Tags: azure, rest, oauth

I need to call the Following azure REST API
GET https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts?api-version=2019-10-01-preview
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/2019-10-01-preview/billing-accounts/list#code-try-0)

I created an app registration. Got a valid authentication Bearer token with this app registration using postman.
When I call the Above REST URL using this token, I get response (200 OK)  with the following empty array JSON in the body; `{ "value": []}`

However, when I use the Microsoft Rest API try out option(check the MS docs link above) and login using the same tenant as the app registration. I get valid result with billing accounts. I copied the bearer token from the network request in the developer tools on the browser. and used this token on postman along with the API call, which also works and give me the billing accounts JSON back.

I'm not sure what am I missing? Why cant I get the billing information using my app registration ?

Role assignments(screenshot)
[image: Role Assignments-screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The REST API endpoint...

> Lists the billing accounts that a user *has access to*.

Looks like the app registration you're using to call the API endpoint doesn't have access to any billing accounts. The fact that the call returns Status code 200 means "OK. The request has succeeded.".

Here's how to [Give others access to view billing information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/manage-billing-access#give-others-access-to-view-billing-information).

> Account administrator can grant others access to Azure billing information by assigning one of the following roles on a subscription in their account.
>
> - Service Administrator
> - Co-administrator
> - Owner
> - Contributor
> - Reader
> - Billing reader
>
> These roles have access to billing information in the Azure portal. People that are assigned these roles can also use the Billing APIs to programmatically get invoices and usage details.
>
> **Note**
> If you're an EA customer, an Account Owner can assign the above role to other users of their team. But for these users to view billing information, the Enterprise Administrator must enable AO view charges in the Enterprise portal.

Comment: I think I've added the required role assignments. But still no results. See the added screenshot .